# Is every graph with minimum degree k a supergraph of some graph with maximum degree k?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $S$ be the set of all possible graphs with maximum degree $k$. Is every possible graph with minimum degree $k$ a supergraph of some $s \in S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree $k$ than $K_{1,k}$ is the subgraph induced by the vertex $v$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm pretty new at this. Could you elaborate on what is meant by $K_{1,k}$?

Comment: $K_{1,k}$ is the graph consisting of $k+1$ vertices, one of which is the center vertex and $k$ of which are adjacent to this center vertex. It is called a star graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)

Comment: @Budge in general, $K_{m,n}$ is the [complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) on $m+n$ vertices with partition $A,B$, $|A|=m$, $|B|=n$, and every possible edge between the parts.  I.e. $E=\{(a,b)~:~a\in A,~b\in B\}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! Follow-up question for either of you: If we place a bound on the minimum degree of the graphs in $S$ say $k_0$ where $1< k_0 < k$ then will it still be true that every possible graph of minimum degree $k$ will be a supergraph of some $s \in S$?

Comment: @Shahab Ok In the future I will certainly do that in the future! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not convinced yet @Shahab, so I feel it deserves proof.  I am failing to come up with a proper counterexample though.  In this new question, $S'\subsetneq S$.  It could be shown to be false if there is some graph of minimum degree $k$ whose only subgraphs have low minimum degree ($<k_0$) or high maximum degree ($>k$).

Comment: @JMoravitz: What is $S'$?

Comment: In the original question $S=\{G~:~\Delta(G)=k\}$.  To distinguish the set for the new question, $S'=\{G~:~\Delta(G)=k,~\delta(G)\geq k_0\}$.  We have that $S'\subsetneq S$, so the claw graph (which was an easy example for the original question) will no longer work.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't see that and took $S=S'$.

Comment: When you say $k_0$ is "a bound on the minimum degree" does "bound" mean "upper bound" or "lower bound"?

Comment: @bof lower bound is the only reasonable interpretation, since the *star* graph would continue to work as a trivial example otherwise.  (typoed claw for star in previous comment)

Comment: @Budge: Hopefully you have followed these comments so that you are aware that your follow up question is still not solved, unlike what I said previously.

Comment: @Shahab I have been following the comments. I guess I mistakenly convinced myself that your previous comment was correct. Admittedly, I also asked the wrong question in the first place. I originally was concerned with graphs with a fixed number of vertices. But now I am interested in both problems and will ask new questions for each.